# Undefined Index : PHP variables passing by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables

I would like to send my php variables and input file by AJAX with something like this ..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){ 

        //var formData = new FormData($('form#data')[0]);

        var chaID = "<?php echo $chaID; ?>";
        var row_number = "<?php echo $row_number; ?>";
        var tag = "<?php echo $tag; ?>";
        var data = '&chaID=' + chaID + '&row_number=' + row_number + '&tag=' + tag;

        //Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_challenge.php",
            data : data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){

                $('#level').modal('show');

            },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });


        return false;
    });
});
```

My `formData` is working fine so let's focus on `var data`. When I run this function the ajax_challenge.php response "undefined index" but in request part it shown `&chaID=7&row_number=2&tag=6` so it should work.

Maybe I did something wrong with php?

```
$chaID = $_POST['chaID'];
$row_number = $_POST['row_number'];
$tag = $_POST['tag'];
```

Additionally, is there anyway to mix formData + data correctly?

EDIT . the screenshots of browser's console

[response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TviZj.png)

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBVKt.png)

**EDIT2** -----------------------------------------------------------

The thing is, it's gonna work if I remove

```
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
```

but the problem is If I deleted it also can't pass `var formData` input:file through URL. What do I suppose to do ?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Hi @JayBlanchard, yes i've watched it the response keep showing undefined index but request displayed &chaID=7&row_number=2&tag=6 so It doesn't mean it's already corrected the values?

Comment: just you need change this `'&chaID=' + chaID + '&row_number=' + row_number + '&tag=' + tag;` on this `'?chaID=' + chaID + '&row_number=' + row_number + '&tag=' + tag;` you have no valid post data.

Comment: Put those PHP variables into hidden form fields that will get picked up by `FormData`,

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hey It request `?chaID=2&row_number=3&tag=7` right now but still not work .__.

Comment: What do you mean by "still not work"? The data doesn't get transmitted? Are those PHP values there when you run the page?

Comment: seems all data got transmitted but it's still undefined index T.T;

Comment: I'm really sorry if i did something inappropriately. I'm a quite newbie here thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see what is going on, you're passing the GET parameters wrong to the data variable.

From my understanding of how jQuery appends GET parameters, the fix would be

```
'?chaID=' + chaID + '&row_number=' + row_number + '&tag=' + tag
```

If this doesn't solve it, try checking the console for errors or try to `console.log` the values. Also make sure you're `encodeURI` the values before putting them in the URL.

Also, it's better practice to make an array with the GET values and pass them instead to the data variable of the jQuery.ajax() function, as it does the string conversion for you automatically, try doing that instead, it might just solve the problem. ;)

You can find the documentation for the AJAX functions of jQuery and EncodeURI here:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

EDIT: I noticed you're using the POST method, in that case then pass the array of posted values to the data parameter and it should work. Only include the variable values however. Example array:

```
data = [chaID, row_number, tag];
```

Pass an array to the data parameter, and it should post the values just fine. Also, try to include in your question a screenshot of the console network tab, which tells us if something is going wrong. Also a console screenshot.

EDIT2: Okay, here are my observations: ProcessData will process the object, therefore it makes sense formData won't work. Try appending the other array:

```
data = [chaID, row_number, tag];
for (var i = 0; i < formData.length; i++) {
    data.append('formData[]', formData[i]);
}
```

**EDIT3: This should work. Just modify your PHP and JS this way:**

```
  var data = formData;
  var params = $.param({"chaID": chaID, "row_number": row_number, "tag": tag});


//Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_challenge.php?" + params,
data : data ,
```

and PHP:

```
$chaID = $_GET['chaID'];
$row_number = $_GET['row_number'];
$tag = $_GET['tag'];
```

Comment: okay I'd try to make array instead ._. I fixed a syntax and still not work

Comment: @devpro OH I didn't notice he was POSTing instead of GETing, in that case it has to be an obligatory array of values.

Comment: if OP want to use $_GET than just add `?` as i mentioned in my answer any way good effort... bro , vote for u

Comment: @devpro thank you so much, I will correct the answer

Comment: @SergioE.Diaz I've already edited and included screenshots please take a look. I'm still stuck

Comment: Would you go to see my second edit again ._. ? I can fix it but There is a new problem here. @SergioE.Diaz

Comment: @NongkarnttNitchkarnt Edited.

Comment: @SergioE.Diaz sorry for my dumb.but all I have to do is var your data and for loop, then type `data : data` in ajax function with no ` contentType: false, processData: false` right? I did it and can't defined everything right now. I'm feeling so sorry T__T ;

Comment: It's okay @NongkarnttNitchkarnt, we were all new to this once ;)

Comment: @NongkarnttNitchkarnt And yes, it should work. A workaround to this too would be to serialize the FormData and simply send it as GET while sending the other data as POST. It should work. It's a bit hackish but it should work just fine.

Comment: http://upic.me/show/57954010 that is all my script right now, should i do change anything with my var formData it's a bit weird @SergioE.Diaz

Comment: and this is what console.log show me `["7", "2", "6"]` @SergioE.Diaz

Comment: Put your script on a JSFiddle so I can edit it and help you solve it better. @NongkarnttNitchkarnt

Comment: @NongkarnttNitchkarnt Haha okay I'll take a look at it. One minute. Also, paste the HTML so the formdata works.

Comment: @NongkarnttNitchkarnt Edit 3 should fix it all.

Comment: I'm sorry please forgive me.but how can I access Edit 3 ? @SergioE.Diaz

Comment: OMG let me kill myself right hereeee @SergioE.Diaz I thought u mean in fiddle I'm SORRY T_T

Comment: It's work now ! Wonderful .. I can't explain how much I love you @SergioE.Diaz sorry for being annoy >_<;

Answer (score 1):

Because you put your php variable to your script. And php compile your code first your javascript run:

```
var chaID = "<?php echo $chaID; ?>";
    var row_number = "<?php echo $row_number; ?>";
    var tag = "<?php echo $tag; ?>";
    var data = '&chaID=' + chaID + '&row_number=' + row_number + '&tag=' + tag;
```

And so, you have not click, $_POST['chaID'] and another $_POST variable is not defined.

Comment: This is correct unless the file the script is in is a .php file which gets interpreted first before being outputted. In that case which is usually the case (notice the opening tags), this theory is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `$_POST` method in ajax no need to start param data with `&`

```
var data = '&chaID=' + chaID + '&row_number=' + row_number + '&tag=' + tag;
```

**Replace with:**

```
var data = 'chaID=' + chaID + '&row_number=' + row_number + '&tag=' + tag;
```

Also check values in php what are you getting by using `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: I replaced it with your syntax. print_r is also undefined.

Comment: @nongkarntt-nitchkarnt change this `type: "POST",` into `method:"POST",`